# Put relative position element behind to fixed position element

Tags: html, css

I want to put behind the `button` with position `relative` to the `div` with `postion:fixed`. 
The  purpose of relative position to the `button` is based from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60484939/12708425) of my previews question. From that answers, custom combo box works perfectly as I expected. But The button of the combo box is accessible while showing any pop ups & fixed position elements. For this question, I attached my study code here,

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sticky">
        <div class="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="elements">
        <button>I should behind this green wall!</button>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
 html,body{

    min-height: 100%;
 }

 body{

    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
 }

 .sticky{

    position: sticky;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: orange;
 }

 .fixed{

    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 40px;

    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(34, 138, 34, 0.555);
 }

 .elements{
     background-color: rgb(231, 77, 39);
 }
 .elements button{

    position: relative;
 }
```

**Current Design:**

[image]

**Expected Design:**

[image]

How can I resolve it? Thank you in advance...

Comment: You need to add `z-index` on `.sticky` class like **.sticky{z-index: 2;}**

Comment: @RaeeshAlam, Thank you it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) will set the z-order of `.sticky` and its descendants.

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(34, 138, 34, 0.555);
}

.elements {
  background-color: rgb(231, 77, 39);
}

.elements button {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="sticky">
  <div class="fixed">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="elements">
  <button>I should behind this green wall!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's awesome!